# Scala Regex Match And Replace

Tags: regex, scala

I want to find a pattern `"""("\"\{.*?\}\"")"""` in a string and drop `"{` and `}"` from the start and the end respectively from  all instances of the pattern found in the string.

For example: `"batters": "{{"id":"1001"}}"` should be replaced by `"batters": {"id":"1001"}`

Is there any Regex function that can help me?

Comment: Something like `"""\"batters\": \"{{\"id\":\"1001\"}}\"""".replaceAll("""\"{(.*?)}\"""", "$1")`?

Comment: Hey, @stribizhev, you may forget to escape { in """\"{(.*?)}\"""", java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException is thrown when running the code.

Comment: Whatever. You answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happen to see a detailed explanation about this usage of regular expression in JavaScript: The Definitive Guide 6th Edition **10.2 String Methods for Pattern Matching**

> Recall that parenthesized subexpressions of a regular expression are 
>   numbered from left to right and that the regular expression remembers 
>   the text that each subexpression matches. If a $ followed by a digit 
>   appears in the replacement string, replace() replaces those two 
>   characters with the text that matches the specified subexpression

```
scala> """"{{"id":"1001"}}"""".replaceAll("""\"\{(.*?)\}\"""", "$1")
res15: String = {"id":"1001"}
```

The code above should solve you problem.